# textファイルからランダムで行を表示、5%の確率でtextファイルにない文言を表示するプログラム

Tags: java

scannerとrandomクラスの組み合わせ方が分からず困っております。

5%の確率でやかんを出してくるドラえもんプログラム
ひみつ道具の一覧をテキストファイルで作成し、起動時に読み込む。 テキストは一行に一つひみつ道具名を記載する。
Enter を入力するたび、5%の確率で「やかん」と喋り、95%の確率で一覧のいずれかのひ みつ道具の名称を喋る。
”end”と入力したらプログラム終了。
例）「スモールライト～」 （道具名+～)
　　　「どんぶら粉～」

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Question{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "txt"));         

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // process the line.
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        ｝
```

Answer (score 0):

一度ファイルから読み取った文字列をListや配列等に格納してください。
その後、入力毎に乱数で処理してください。
提示したコードを元にした実装例は以下のようになります。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "items.txt";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)));         

            String line;
            
            //入力を格納するList
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // ファイル内のデータを１行毎にリストへ格納する
                list.add(line);             
            }
            // 乱数オブジェクトの生成
            Random rnd = new Random();
            // Scannerオブジェクトの生成
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
                while(true) {
                    // 改行(Enterを含んだ文字列を入力する)
                    line = sc.nextLine();
                    if("end".equals(line)) {
                        // endと入力したらプログラムを修了する
                        break;
                    }else {
                        if(rnd.nextInt(20)==0) {
                            // 5%の確率でやかんを表示する
                            System.out.println("やかん");
                        }else {
                            // 95%の確率で一覧のいずれかの名称を表示
                            System.out.println(list.get(rnd.nextInt(list.size())));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```